# How to use web-item in html context?

Tags: html, jira, velocity, jira-plugin

I have tab in html list in success.vm:

```
<a href="/path/to/web-item" id="a-link"> A tab </a>
```

And Web-item in atlassian-plugin.xml:

```
<web-item name="Atab" i18n-name-key="atab.name" key="atab" section="project-    
config-group" weight="1000">
  <description key="atab.description">The Atab Plugin</description>
  <label key="atab.label"/>
  <link linkId="atab-link">/secure/TabA.jspa</link>
```

What should i use to refer to web-item in success.vm, in html or through the velocity?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

web-item is only a link pointing somewhere, for example to webwork action. Then the webwork action can have specific .vm template.